# Why don't I have the correct IP address

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Right now I'm trying to wirelessly connect to a raspberry pi but I need the IP. I've been using many different commands but no matter what my IP starts with 10.80 instead of 192. Why is this? What can I do to get the correct IP? (I'm using wireless WIFI not ethernet.

Comment: What system are you trying to connect from? And what is its IP address? Can you connect to the router/access-point the RasPi is connecting to? Do you have an iPad or iPhone or something that can run the app called `fing` ?

Comment: I'm just using remote desktop connection to try to connect to it. I do not have any apple products. And I don't know what the router/access-point the RaspiPi is connecting to.